# Center a submit button div

Tags: html, css

I have styled a submit button and would like to center it.  Here is the CSS:

```
.outer {
    text-align: center;
}

/* BUTTONS */

.buttons button{
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
border: 0;
height: 28px;
float: left;
text-indent: 4px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1.2em;
background: url(../images/button.png);
}

.buttons span{ /* Right-hand corner */
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
display: block;
width: 5px;
height: 28px;
float: left;
background: url(../images/button.png) top right;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="buttons">
      <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button><span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I copied this code from http://www.scottking.com.au/blog/2009/03/custom-styled-css-html-input-buttons/#.Uc2IYdjcAix

So far have been unable to center align this button.

Comment: By center align, do you mean the button text, or the button itself in it's parent container?

Comment: You could do `.outer .buttons { display:inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` Compatibility goes back to IE 7 I think.

```
.outer .buttons {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AVtjQ/

EDIT: [compatibility will go back to IE6](http://caniuse.com/inline-block) if you change your div to a naturally inline element like a span.

Answer (score 1):

Give .`outer` an auto margin and a width: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/Ctab4/

CSS

```
.outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .buttons

```
.outer .buttons { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw a

```
 div.buttons {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

in there.

Comment: Tried, unfortunately no change in left align behavour

Comment: Can we see some more of the code? Have a feeling something else is going on here. Are they in another div? Is that the whole css file?

Answer (score 0):

margin-left: 50%
margin-right: auto

I think this will work, you might need to fiddle with the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS replace you code with this one

```
.outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
}

/* BUTTONS */

.buttons button{

cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
border: 0;
height: 28px;
float: left;
text-indent: 4px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1.2em;
background: url(../images/button.png);
}

.buttons span{ /* Right-hand corner */
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
display: block;
width: 5px;
height: 28px;
float: left;
background: url(../images/button.png) top right;
}
```